# Turn ratio of an ideal transformer

Tags: transformer, low-pass

I am designing a Chevyshev filter of order \$n=2\$, and I the terminant resistances to be equal (since when performing the denormalization of a low-pass circuit for an even order in Chevychev this never happens) and I can use an ideal transformer. My circuit is the following:
[image]
and I need the following one:

[image]

but my problem is that I don't know how to compute the turn ratio \$n_p:n_s\$ for the 133 ohm resistor to be 50 ohm, does somebody know how to achieve this? Also, the voltage of the sources is not specified (I don't know if that is relevant)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns ratio goes as the square root of the impedance ratio.

\$\sqrt{\frac{133}{50}}=1.63\$